# Lightbox2 Not Spawning in IE7/8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, lightbox2

I have an issue when spawning a lightbox object in ie7/8.

The overlay appears but not the image loader or the image itself.

Example:

In Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

In IE8
[image: IE8]

This is my Lightbox.js:

```
(function () {
    var $, Lightbox, LightboxOptions;

    $ = jQuery;

    LightboxOptions = (function () {

        function LightboxOptions() {
            this.fileLoadingImage = '../bundles/lightbox/images/loading.gif';
            this.fileCloseImage = '../bundles/lightbox/images/close.png';
            this.resizeDuration = 700;
            this.fadeDuration = 500;
            this.labelImage = "Image";
            this.labelOf = "of";
        }

        return LightboxOptions;

    })();

    Lightbox = (function () {

        function Lightbox(options) {
            this.options = options;
            this.album = [];
            this.currentImageIndex = void 0;
            this.init();
        }

        Lightbox.prototype.init = function () {
            this.enable();
            return this.build();
        };

        Lightbox.prototype.enable = function () {
            var _this = this;
            return $('body').on('click', 'a[class^=lightbox], area[class^=lightbox]', function (e) {
                _this.start($(e.currentTarget));
                return false;
            });
        };

        Lightbox.prototype.build = function () {
            var $lightbox,
            _this = this;
            $("<div>", {
                id: 'lightboxOverlay'
            }).after($('<div/>', {
                id: 'lightbox'
            }).append($('<div/>', {
                "class": 'lb-outerContainer'
            }).append($('<div/>', {
                "class": 'lb-container'
            }).append($('<img/>', {
                "class": 'lb-image'
            }), $('<div/>', {
                "class": 'lb-nav'
            }).append($('<a/>', {
                "class": 'lb-prev'
            }), $('<a/>', {
                "class": 'lb-next'
            })), $('<div/>', {
                "class": 'lb-loader'
            }).append($('<a/>', {
                "class": 'lb-cancel'
            }).append($('<img/>', {
                src: this.options.fileLoadingImage
            }))))), $('<div/>', {
                "class": 'lb-dataContainer'
            }).append($('<div/>', {
                "class": 'lb-data'
            }).append($('<div/>', {
                "class": 'lb-details'
            }).append($('<span/>', {
                "class": 'lb-caption'
            }), $('<span/>', {
                "class": 'lb-number'
            })), $('<div/>', {
                "class": 'lb-closeContainer'
            }).append($('<a/>', {
                "class": 'lb-close'
            }).append($('<img/>', {
                src: this.options.fileCloseImage
            }))))))).appendTo($('body'));
            $('#lightboxOverlay').hide().on('click', function (e) {
                _this.end();
                return false;
            });
            $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
            $lightbox.hide().on('click', function (e) {
                if ($(e.target).attr('id') === 'lightbox') _this.end();
                return false;
            });
            $lightbox.find('.lb-outerContainer').on('click', function (e) {
                if ($(e.target).attr('id') === 'lightbox') _this.end();
                return false;
            });
            $lightbox.find('.lb-prev').on('click', function (e) {
                _this.changeImage(_this.currentImageIndex - 1);
                return false;
            });
            $lightbox.find('.lb-next').on('click', function (e) {
                _this.changeImage(_this.currentImageIndex + 1);
                return false;
            });
            $lightbox.find('.lb-loader, .lb-close').on('click', function (e) {
                _this.end();
                return false;
            });
        };

        Lightbox.prototype.start = function ($link) {
            var $lightbox, $window, a, i, imageNumber, left, top, _len, _ref;
            $(window).on("resize", this.sizeOverlay);
            $('select, object, embed').css({
                visibility: "hidden"
            });
            $('#lightboxOverlay').width($(document).width()).height($(document).height()).fadeIn(this.options.fadeDuration);
            this.album = [];
            imageNumber = 0;
            if ($link.attr('class') === 'lightbox') {
                this.album.push({
                    link: $link.attr('href'),
                    title: $link.attr('title')
                });
            } else {
                _ref = $($link.prop("tagName") + '[class="' + $link.attr('class') + '"]');
                for (i = 0, _len = _ref.length; i < _len; i++) {
                    a = _ref[i];
                    this.album.push({
                        link: $(a).attr('href'),
                        title: $(a).attr('title')
                    });
                    if ($(a).attr('href') === $link.attr('href')) imageNumber = i;
                }
            }
            $window = $(window);
            top = $window.scrollTop() + $window.height() / 10;
            left = $window.scrollLeft();
            $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
            $lightbox.css({
                top: top + 'px',
                left: left + 'px'
            }).fadeIn(this.options.fadeDuration);
            this.changeImage(imageNumber);
        };

        Lightbox.prototype.changeImage = function (imageNumber) {
            var $image, $lightbox, preloader,
            _this = this;
            this.disableKeyboardNav();
            $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
            $image = $lightbox.find('.lb-image');
            this.sizeOverlay();
            $('#lightboxOverlay').fadeIn(this.options.fadeDuration);
            $('.loader').fadeIn('slow');
            $lightbox.find('.lb-image, .lb-nav, .lb-prev, .lb-next, .lb-dataContainer, .lb-numbers, .lb-caption').hide();
            $lightbox.find('.lb-outerContainer').addClass('animating');
            $lightbox.find('.lb-loader').show();
            preloader = new Image();
            preloader.onload = function () {
                $image.attr('src', _this.album[imageNumber].link);
                $image.width = preloader.width;
                $image.height = preloader.height;
                return _this.sizeContainer(preloader.width, preloader.height);
            };
            preloader.src = this.album[imageNumber].link;
            this.currentImageIndex = imageNumber;
        };

        Lightbox.prototype.sizeOverlay = function () {
            return $('#lightboxOverlay').width($(document).width()).height($(document).height());
        };

        Lightbox.prototype.sizeContainer = function (imageWidth, imageHeight) {
            var $container, $lightbox, $outerContainer, containerBottomPadding, containerLeftPadding, containerRightPadding, containerTopPadding, newHeight, newWidth, oldHeight, oldWidth,
            _this = this;
            $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
            $outerContainer = $lightbox.find('.lb-outerContainer');
            oldWidth = $outerContainer.outerWidth();
            oldHeight = $outerContainer.outerHeight();
            $container = $lightbox.find('.lb-container');
            containerTopPadding = parseInt($container.css('padding-top'), 10);
            containerRightPadding = parseInt($container.css('padding-right'), 10);
            containerBottomPadding = parseInt($container.css('padding-bottom'), 10);
            containerLeftPadding = parseInt($container.css('padding-left'), 10);
            newWidth = imageWidth + containerLeftPadding + containerRightPadding;
            newHeight = imageHeight + containerTopPadding + containerBottomPadding;
            if (newWidth !== oldWidth && newHeight !== oldHeight) {
                $outerContainer.animate({
                    width: newWidth,
                    height: newHeight
                }, this.options.resizeDuration, 'swing');
            } else if (newWidth !== oldWidth) {
                $outerContainer.animate({
                    width: newWidth
                }, this.options.resizeDuration, 'swing');
            } else if (newHeight !== oldHeight) {
                $outerContainer.animate({
                    height: newHeight
                }, this.options.resizeDuration, 'swing');
            }
            setTimeout(function () {
                $lightbox.find('.lb-dataContainer').width(newWidth);
                $lightbox.find('.lb-prevLink').height(newHeight);
                $lightbox.find('.lb-nextLink').height(newHeight);
                _this.showImage();
            }, this.options.resizeDuration);
        };

        Lightbox.prototype.showImage = function () {
            var $lightbox;
            $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
            $lightbox.find('.lb-loader').hide();
            $lightbox.find('.lb-image').fadeIn('slow');
            this.updateNav();
            this.updateDetails();
            this.preloadNeighboringImages();
            this.enableKeyboardNav();
        };

        Lightbox.prototype.updateNav = function () {
            var $lightbox;
            $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
            $lightbox.find('.lb-nav').show();
            if (this.currentImageIndex > 0) $lightbox.find('.lb-prev').show();
            if (this.currentImageIndex < this.album.length - 1) {
                $lightbox.find('.lb-next').show();
            }
        };

        Lightbox.prototype.updateDetails = function () {
            var $lightbox,
            _this = this;
            $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
            if (typeof this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title !== 'undefined' && this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title !== "") {
                $lightbox.find('.lb-caption').html(this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (this.album.length > 1) {
                $lightbox.find('.lb-number').html(this.options.labelImage + ' ' + (this.currentImageIndex + 1) + ' ' + this.options.labelOf + '  ' + this.album.length).fadeIn('fast');
            } else {
                $lightbox.find('.lb-number').hide();
            }
            $lightbox.find('.lb-outerContainer').removeClass('animating');
            $lightbox.find('.lb-dataContainer').fadeIn(this.resizeDuration, function () {
                return _this.sizeOverlay();
            });
        };

        Lightbox.prototype.preloadNeighboringImages = function () {
            var preloadNext, preloadPrev;
            if (this.album.length > this.currentImageIndex + 1) {
                preloadNext = new Image();
                preloadNext.src = this.album[this.currentImageIndex + 1].link;
            }
            if (this.currentImageIndex > 0) {
                preloadPrev = new Image();
                preloadPrev.src = this.album[this.currentImageIndex - 1].link;
            }
        };

        Lightbox.prototype.enableKeyboardNav = function () {
            $(document).on('keyup.keyboard', $.proxy(this.keyboardAction, this));
        };

        Lightbox.prototype.disableKeyboardNav = function () {
            $(document).off('.keyboard');
        };

        Lightbox.prototype.keyboardAction = function (event) {
            var KEYCODE_ESC, KEYCODE_LEFTARROW, KEYCODE_RIGHTARROW, key, keycode;
            KEYCODE_ESC = 27;
            KEYCODE_LEFTARROW = 37;
            KEYCODE_RIGHTARROW = 39;
            keycode = event.keyCode;
            key = String.fromCharCode(keycode).toLowerCase();
            if (keycode === KEYCODE_ESC || key.match(/x|o|c/)) {
                this.end();
            } else if (key === 'p' || keycode === KEYCODE_LEFTARROW) {
                if (this.currentImageIndex !== 0) {
                    this.changeImage(this.currentImageIndex - 1);
                }
            } else if (key === 'n' || keycode === KEYCODE_RIGHTARROW) {
                if (this.currentImageIndex !== this.album.length - 1) {
                    this.changeImage(this.currentImageIndex + 1);
                }
            }
        };

        Lightbox.prototype.end = function () {
            this.disableKeyboardNav();
            $(window).off("resize", this.sizeOverlay);
            $('#lightbox').fadeOut(this.options.fadeDuration);
            $('#lightboxOverlay').fadeOut(this.options.fadeDuration);
            return $('select, object, embed').css({
                visibility: "visible"
            });
        };

        return Lightbox;

    })();

    $(function () {
        var lightbox, options;
        options = new LightboxOptions();
        lightbox = new Lightbox(options);
        return lightbox;
    });

}).call(this);
```

This code works for Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

I am unsure as to what is causing the issue, I have gone through the console and there are no errors produced.

Any help would be appriciated.

Here is a [Link](http://ge.verscreative.co.uk/portfolio/images.php?cid=2&subid=7) to the test page

Comment: The problems are caused by the html5shiv.js file which is added to deal with HTML5 markup. You could simply remove the script from the webpage and the Lightbox would function properly on either IE7 or IE8. There is a discussion about this issue on the Lightbox forum: http://lokeshdhakar.com/forums/index.php?p=/discussion/5486/lightbox-doesn039t-work-in-internet-explorer-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Here everyone:

https://github.com/sibprogrammer/lightbox2/commit/002a6396d07ee0aea0a87e7cc3e86b5ce5f395cd

Compatibility Fix for html5shiv.

Full lightbox.js

```
(function() {
  var $, Lightbox, LightboxOptions;

  $ = jQuery;

  LightboxOptions = (function() {

    function LightboxOptions() {
      this.fileLoadingImage = '../bundles/lightbox/images/loading.gif';
      this.fileCloseImage = '../bundles/lightbox/images/close.png';
      this.resizeDuration = 700;
      this.fadeDuration = 500;
      this.labelImage = "Image";
      this.labelOf = "of";
    }

    return LightboxOptions;

  })();

  Lightbox = (function() {

    function Lightbox(options) {
      this.options = options;
      this.album = [];
      this.currentImageIndex = void 0;
      this.init();
    }

    Lightbox.prototype.init = function() {
      this.enable();
      return this.build();
    };

    Lightbox.prototype.enable = function() {
      var _this = this;
      return $('body').on('click', 'a[class^=lightbox], area[class^=lightbox]', function(e) {
        _this.start($(e.currentTarget));
        return false;
      });
    };

    Lightbox.prototype.build = function() {
      var $lightbox,
        _this = this;
      $("<div>", {
        id: 'lightboxOverlay'
      }).appendTo($('body'));
      $('<div/>', {
        id: 'lightbox'
      }).append($('<div/>', {
        "class": 'lb-outerContainer'
      }).append($('<div/>', {
        "class": 'lb-container'
      }).append($('<img/>', {
        "class": 'lb-image'
      }), $('<div/>', {
        "class": 'lb-nav'
      }).append($('<a/>', {
        "class": 'lb-prev'
      }), $('<a/>', {
        "class": 'lb-next'
      })), $('<div/>', {
        "class": 'lb-loader'
      }).append($('<a/>', {
        "class": 'lb-cancel'
      }).append($('<img/>', {
        src: this.options.fileLoadingImage
      }))))), $('<div/>', {
        "class": 'lb-dataContainer'
      }).append($('<div/>', {
        "class": 'lb-data'
      }).append($('<div/>', {
        "class": 'lb-details'
      }).append($('<span/>', {
        "class": 'lb-caption'
      }), $('<span/>', {
        "class": 'lb-number'
      })), $('<div/>', {
        "class": 'lb-closeContainer'
      }).append($('<a/>', {
        "class": 'lb-close'
      }).append($('<img/>', {
        src: this.options.fileCloseImage
      })))))).appendTo($('body'));
      $('#lightboxOverlay').hide().on('click', function(e) {
        _this.end();
        return false;
      });
      $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
      $lightbox.hide().on('click', function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).attr('id') === 'lightbox') _this.end();
        return false;
      });
      $lightbox.find('.lb-outerContainer').on('click', function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).attr('id') === 'lightbox') _this.end();
        return false;
      });
      $lightbox.find('.lb-prev').on('click', function(e) {
        _this.changeImage(_this.currentImageIndex - 1);
        return false;
      });
      $lightbox.find('.lb-next').on('click', function(e) {
        _this.changeImage(_this.currentImageIndex + 1);
        return false;
      });
      $lightbox.find('.lb-loader, .lb-close').on('click', function(e) {
        _this.end();
        return false;
      });
    };

    Lightbox.prototype.start = function($link) {
      var $lightbox, $window, a, i, imageNumber, left, top, _len, _ref;
      $(window).on("resize", this.sizeOverlay);
      $('select, object, embed').css({
        visibility: "hidden"
      });
      $('#lightboxOverlay').width($(document).width()).height($(document).height()).fadeIn(this.options.fadeDuration);
      this.album = [];
      imageNumber = 0;
      if ($link.attr('rel') === 'lightbox') {
        this.album.push({
          link: $link.attr('href'),
          title: $link.attr('title')
        });
      } else {
        _ref = $($link.prop("tagName") + '[class="' + $link.attr('class') + '"]');
        for (i = 0, _len = _ref.length; i < _len; i++) {
          a = _ref[i];
          this.album.push({
            link: $(a).attr('href'),
            title: $(a).attr('title')
          });
          if ($(a).attr('href') === $link.attr('href')) imageNumber = i;
        }
      }
      $window = $(window);
      top = $window.scrollTop() + $window.height() / 10;
      left = $window.scrollLeft();
      $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
      $lightbox.css({
        top: top + 'px',
        left: left + 'px'
      }).fadeIn(this.options.fadeDuration);
      this.changeImage(imageNumber);
    };

    Lightbox.prototype.changeImage = function(imageNumber) {
      var $image, $lightbox, preloader,
        _this = this;
      this.disableKeyboardNav();
      $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
      $image = $lightbox.find('.lb-image');
      this.sizeOverlay();
      $('#lightboxOverlay').fadeIn(this.options.fadeDuration);
      $('.loader').fadeIn('slow');
      $lightbox.find('.lb-image, .lb-nav, .lb-prev, .lb-next, .lb-dataContainer, .lb-numbers, .lb-caption').hide();
      $lightbox.find('.lb-outerContainer').addClass('animating');
      preloader = new Image;
      preloader.onload = function() {
        $image.attr('src', _this.album[imageNumber].link);
        $image.width = preloader.width;
        $image.height = preloader.height;
        return _this.sizeContainer(preloader.width, preloader.height);
      };
      preloader.src = this.album[imageNumber].link;
      this.currentImageIndex = imageNumber;
    };

    Lightbox.prototype.sizeOverlay = function() {
      return $('#lightboxOverlay').width($(document).width()).height($(document).height());
    };

    Lightbox.prototype.sizeContainer = function(imageWidth, imageHeight) {
      var $container, $lightbox, $outerContainer, containerBottomPadding, containerLeftPadding, containerRightPadding, containerTopPadding, newHeight, newWidth, oldHeight, oldWidth,
        _this = this;
      $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
      $outerContainer = $lightbox.find('.lb-outerContainer');
      oldWidth = $outerContainer.outerWidth();
      oldHeight = $outerContainer.outerHeight();
      $container = $lightbox.find('.lb-container');
      containerTopPadding = parseInt($container.css('padding-top'), 10);
      containerRightPadding = parseInt($container.css('padding-right'), 10);
      containerBottomPadding = parseInt($container.css('padding-bottom'), 10);
      containerLeftPadding = parseInt($container.css('padding-left'), 10);
      newWidth = imageWidth + containerLeftPadding + containerRightPadding;
      newHeight = imageHeight + containerTopPadding + containerBottomPadding;
      if (newWidth !== oldWidth && newHeight !== oldHeight) {
        $outerContainer.animate({
          width: newWidth,
          height: newHeight
        }, this.options.resizeDuration, 'swing');
      } else if (newWidth !== oldWidth) {
        $outerContainer.animate({
          width: newWidth
        }, this.options.resizeDuration, 'swing');
      } else if (newHeight !== oldHeight) {
        $outerContainer.animate({
          height: newHeight
        }, this.options.resizeDuration, 'swing');
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
        $lightbox.find('.lb-dataContainer').width(newWidth);
        $lightbox.find('.lb-prevLink').height(newHeight);
        $lightbox.find('.lb-nextLink').height(newHeight);
        _this.showImage();
      }, this.options.resizeDuration);
    };

    Lightbox.prototype.showImage = function() {
      var $lightbox;
      $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
      $lightbox.find('.lb-loader').hide();
      $lightbox.find('.lb-image').fadeIn('slow');
      this.updateNav();
      this.updateDetails();
      this.preloadNeighboringImages();
      this.enableKeyboardNav();
    };

    Lightbox.prototype.updateNav = function() {
      var $lightbox;
      $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
      $lightbox.find('.lb-nav').show();
      if (this.currentImageIndex > 0) $lightbox.find('.lb-prev').show();
      if (this.currentImageIndex < this.album.length - 1) {
        $lightbox.find('.lb-next').show();
      }
    };

    Lightbox.prototype.updateDetails = function() {
      var $lightbox,
        _this = this;
      $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
      if (typeof this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title !== 'undefined' && this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title !== "") {
        $lightbox.find('.lb-caption').html(this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title).fadeIn('fast');
      }
      if (this.album.length > 1) {
        $lightbox.find('.lb-number').html(this.options.labelImage + ' ' + (this.currentImageIndex + 1) + ' ' + this.options.labelOf + '  ' + this.album.length).fadeIn('fast');
      } else {
        $lightbox.find('.lb-number').hide();
      }
      $lightbox.find('.lb-outerContainer').removeClass('animating');
      $lightbox.find('.lb-dataContainer').fadeIn(this.resizeDuration, function() {
        return _this.sizeOverlay();
      });
    };

    Lightbox.prototype.preloadNeighboringImages = function() {
      var preloadNext, preloadPrev;
      if (this.album.length > this.currentImageIndex + 1) {
        preloadNext = new Image;
        preloadNext.src = this.album[this.currentImageIndex + 1].link;
      }
      if (this.currentImageIndex > 0) {
        preloadPrev = new Image;
        preloadPrev.src = this.album[this.currentImageIndex - 1].link;
      }
    };

    Lightbox.prototype.enableKeyboardNav = function() {
      $(document).on('keyup.keyboard', $.proxy(this.keyboardAction, this));
    };

    Lightbox.prototype.disableKeyboardNav = function() {
      $(document).off('.keyboard');
    };

    Lightbox.prototype.keyboardAction = function(event) {
      var KEYCODE_ESC, KEYCODE_LEFTARROW, KEYCODE_RIGHTARROW, key, keycode;
      KEYCODE_ESC = 27;
      KEYCODE_LEFTARROW = 37;
      KEYCODE_RIGHTARROW = 39;
      keycode = event.keyCode;
      key = String.fromCharCode(keycode).toLowerCase();
      if (keycode === KEYCODE_ESC || key.match(/x|o|c/)) {
        this.end();
      } else if (key === 'p' || keycode === KEYCODE_LEFTARROW) {
        if (this.currentImageIndex !== 0) {
          this.changeImage(this.currentImageIndex - 1);
        }
      } else if (key === 'n' || keycode === KEYCODE_RIGHTARROW) {
        if (this.currentImageIndex !== this.album.length - 1) {
          this.changeImage(this.currentImageIndex + 1);
        }
      }
    };

    Lightbox.prototype.end = function() {
      this.disableKeyboardNav();
      $(window).off("resize", this.sizeOverlay);
      $('#lightbox').fadeOut(this.options.fadeDuration);
      $('#lightboxOverlay').fadeOut(this.options.fadeDuration);
      return $('select, object, embed').css({
        visibility: "visible"
      });
    };

    return Lightbox;

  })();

  $(function() {
    var lightbox, options;
    options = new LightboxOptions;
    return lightbox = new Lightbox(options);
  });

}).call(this);
```